# Multitenancy - Get tenant in microservices architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices, software-as-a-service, multitenancy

In a multi-tenant architecture where each tenant has its own database, what would be the best way for each of the microservices to obtain information about the tenant (such as which database to connect to)?

We are still in the modeling phase of the application. We are having difficulty to come up with the best design. We are currently thinking about doing this:

1. The user logs in to the application. Our authentication server
   (IdentityServer 4) returns the user's information along with the
   tenant_id he belongs to (this information is in a claim).
2. The application directs the user to a specific tentant subdomain.
3. The frontend communicates with an API Gateway. Through a Claim,
   the API Gateway knows the tenant through  the claim of the logged user.
4. The API Gateway calls each of the microservices calling the
   tenant_id as a parameter in the endpoint.
5. The microservice receives tenant_id as a parameter and executes a
   query in Redis to obtain the connection string from the database.

We don't know if this is the best solution. We think it is being a lot of work to have to inform tenant_id as parameter in all endpoints of all microservices. We appreciate all the help and suggestions.

Comment: So n MS, n Tenants, n DBs and 1 service to rule them all and into the darkness bind'em? It doesn't sound promising :-) . Why don't you just **deploy** n MS with different configurations? *1 deploy per tant/db* ?

Answer (score 1):

> In a multi-tenant architecture where each tenant has its own database,
> what would be the best way for each of the microservices to obtain
> information about the tenant (such as which database to connect to)?

Agnosticism and a lot of parametrization.

Make the MS agnostic to the concept "tenancy". How to do so? Parametrizing the data source. By configuration, each MS will use only 1 database (or 1 schema in the unique DB, or whatever) and it won't care if such DB is tenant A's DB or tenant B's DB. It's just a database. It will be using always the same database unless you change its configuration.

From the deployment view, it takes to deploy 1 MS per tenant/configuration.

But you don't just deploy n MS to the wild. You have to build clusters per tenant. Each cluster has all the MS required, scaled accordingly and replicated (if needed).

As you may guess by now, this is a lot of MS running.

You might find this unaffordable, but the original approach of relaying on 1 service complicates things considerably. For example, testing. No to mention that if such a dependency fails, **all tenants** will be upset with you. Not one nor two, all of them.

Comment: What about including a tenant Id in the payload of all messages sent to each microservice? Each micro service could keep its own list of databases to connect to, which would probably make polyglot persistence easier. You keep the knowledge of how to connect in the microservice. Each service can share the load across tenants. It puts more pressure to scale the data storage properly though, but would be easier than cloning your prod environment for each tenant.

Comment: And depending on the micro service, you might not need multiple databases. Depends on load, sensitivity of data and regulatory requirements.

Comment: Because its a cognitive and programming burden

Comment: Here the múltiple DB is not due to MS is due to tenantcy. At least It has been stated that way.